# How to implement Semaphores in python 2.x when not using default RUN method

Tags: python, python-2.7, thread-safety

The code flow is something as below.

```
result = []
def Discover(myList=[]):
    for item in myList: 
        t = threading.Thread(target=myFunc, Args=[item])
        t.start()

def myFunc(item):
    result.append(item+item)
```

Now this will start multiple threads and in current scenario the threads does some memory intensive Tasks. Thus I want to include semaphores in this so that myList behaves as a queue and number of threads must be in a limited size. What is the better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Never use mutable objects as default parameter value in function definition. In your case: `def Discover(myList=[])`
2. Use `Queue.Queue` instead of `list` to provide `myList` if it's necessary to update list of "tasks" when threads are running. Or... Use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` in order to limit number of running threads at the same time.
3. Use `Queue.Queue` instead of `list` to provide `results` variable. `list` implementation is not thread-safe, so you probably will get many problems with it.
4. You can find some examples in other SO questions, i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies).

P.S. `ThreadPool` available in Python 2.7+

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
>>> ThreadPool
<class 'multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool'>
```

Comment: I dont see ThreadPool in 2.7. IF there is any library I need to install, and I am using queue only. the question was just in perspective to use semaphores.